# Extremely basic topology question - check my answer

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

I am starting a topology course this monday (or rather, advanced calculus but the first topic we deal with is topology) and I've never did questions like this before. I'd just like someone to verify that I have the right idea of what's going on, and also I have a few questions.

**Question**

Let $A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | x^2 \leq y\}$

Find the interior of $A$, the closure of $A$, and the boundary of $A$.
Is $A$ an open set? Is it a closed set?

**My answers**

$A$ is not an open set. For example, $(1,1) \in A$ but if we look at a circle with $(1,1)$ in the center, and with radius $\epsilon$ as small as we wish, not all the elements in that circle will belong to $A$. For example, $(1+\epsilon,1) \notin A$. So $A$ is not an open set. (**QUESTION 1** can we automatically infer that if $A$ is not an open set, it is a closed set?)

$A$ is a closed set, because $\bar A = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 | x^2 >y\}$ is an open set. for every $(a,b)\in \bar A$ we can find an $\epsilon$ such that all the elements in the circle originating from $(a,b)$ with a radius of $\epsilon$ are in $\bar A$.

The boundary of $A$ is $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | x^2=y\}$

The interior of $A$ is $A$/boundary of $A$ = $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2|x^2<y\}$

The closure of $A$ is $A$ (**QUESTION 2** if $A$ is a closed set, is $A$ = the closure of $A$? This sits well logically but remains to be proven).

Comment: From not open we cannot infer closed. Example: In $\mathbb{R}$, the interval $[0,1)$ is neither open nor closed. And it is *closure*, not enclosure. Yes, if $A$ is closed then the closure of $A$ is $A$.

Comment: Then the way to determine if a set is closed, is to determine if the complement is an open set?

Comment: Yes, that is one way to do it. Once you have some machinery (theorems), there may be faster ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answers are correct. For "not open" it would have been easier to use the point $(0,0)$, since for any $\epsilon\gt 0$ it is clear that the point $(0,-\epsilon/2)$ is in the open disk with centre $(0,0)$ and radius $\epsilon$, and is not in $A$.

For the boundary, an argument should have been given. Part of it is close to what you wrote about $(1+\epsilon,\epsilon)$. You also need to show that nothing else is on the boundary.

From not open we cannot infer closed. Example: In $\mathbb{R}$, the interval $[0,1)$ is neither open nor closed.

And it is *closure*, not *enclosure*. Yes, if $A$ is closed then the closure of $A$ is $A$.

Comment: Is there a formal proof for if $A$ is a closed set then $A=cl(A)$? Also, does it work both ways? $A=cl(A)$ if and only if $A$ is a closed set?

Comment: The closure of $A$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$.  Since $A$ is closed, it is equal to its closure.

Comment: Yes, it is if and only if. It follows immediately from the *definition* of closure.